How to Add Extra Column to BigQuery Schema Dynamically via Airflow GCSToBigQueryOperator
I'm currently working with the Airflow operator GCSToBigQueryOperator and have encountered a scenario where I need to incorporate an ingestion_date into my files stored on Google Cloud Storage (GCS), without directly updating the files themselves.
To achieve this, I've utilized the schema_fields parameter to include ingestion_date in the schema definition, and I intend to continuously update this ingestion_date within the schema.
Is there a way to achieve this??
I tried to use ignore_unknown_values parameter but it allow extra values that are not represented in the schema(Documentation ) But not the opposite. I would like to allow extra columns that are present in the schema but not in the tables schema(GCS files)!
Example, I would like to achieve the following:
The source schema looks like this
[{"name": "id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
          {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
          {"name": "type", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]

And the schema looks like
[ {"name": "id", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "type", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "ingestion_date", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE", "value": "2024-05-01"}

]

Looks like the error is about column_name: "ingestion_date"
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 100. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.invalid, location: gs://temp_dev_test/bo/cdata_2024-05-04.csv, message: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 10, but line contains only 10 columns.; byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 103708795 column_index: 10 column_name: "ingestion_date" column_type: DATE

Is there a workaround or method to address this specific requirement without adding extra process of updating the files and adding ingestion_date?
